# Function declaration warning: Return value of function ‘f’ at (1) not set [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: fortran, gfortran, geany

My code does compile, but with an error:

```
Warning: Return value of function ‘f’ at (1) not set [-Wreturn-type].
```

I use geany. Below is my code.

```
        program ROVNICANEWTON

        implicit none

        integer k
        double precision x0, f, df

        k=0
        x0=2d0

        if (abs(f(x0)) .lt. (0.0000000001)) then
         go to 20
        else
         k=k+1
         x0=x0-f(x0)/df(x0)
         print *, k 
        end if

20     continue    

    open(30, file='NEWTON.txt', status='unknown')
        write(30,*) 'x = ', x0  
    close(30)    
        END PROGRAM

        double precision function f(x)
        implicit none
        double precision, intent(in) :: x

        f(x)=(x**(x**2))-1000

        return
        end function f

        double precision function df(x)
        implicit none
        double precision, intent(in) :: x

        df(x)=2*x**(2+x**2)

        return
        end function df
```

Comment: I suspect you mean `f=...` rather than `f(x)=...`.  Is that so? And the same for `df`.

Comment: btw I now I made another mistake but not syntactical, forgot to put go to after end if and label before if so it will make a loop :) just for further clarification for future readers

Comment: I wonder who teaches such ancient techniques at our alma mater.

Comment: Faculty of chemical physics. I use Fortran for my bachelor thesis and this code is for another subject where we had free hand of choosing which programming language we want to use. Since I already use Fortran, I decided that it would be an exercise for me.

Answer (score 2):

The error message in this case is, I think, leading you astray. It suggests that you're not creating a return value for the function, when in fact the line where you attempt to do just that is syntactically incorrect.

Remember that whenever the function is executed, `x` will have a specific value, and so must the return value `f`:

```
double precision function f(x)
    implicit none
    double precision, intent(in) :: x
    f = (x**(x**2)) - 1000
end function f
```

Similarly, you need to drop the `(x)` from the line `df(x)=2*x**(2+x**2)`

I also don't like you using `goto` in this case. Many times when you think of using a `goto` there is a better, less interrupting way.

That's because a `goto` interrupts the flow of the source code. It makes it harder to follow.

What you want in this case is *do this until a condition is met*. There are two ways to make it easier to read:

```
do
    if (abs(f(x0)) < 1d-10) exit
    k = k + 1
    x0 = x0 - f(x0)/df(x0)
    print *, k
end do
```

Or, even more specific:

```
do while (abs(f(x0)) >= 1d-10)
    k = k + 1
    x0 = x0 - f(x0)/df(x0)
    print *, k
end do
```

Comment: Thank you so much, make sense! It is working now :)

Comment: *I also don't like you using goto in this case.*  You could go further, and state something like *current software engineering best practices advise strongly against using `goto` in they way your code does* lest OP thinks that you are a lone voice howling in the wind.

Comment: Is while implemented in Fortran? I thought while and repeat until loops have to be made with go to statements in this language. This is new to me. Even that exit...

Comment: `DO WHILE` and `EXIT` have been introduced in 1978 and certainly been part of the official standard by Fortran 90. What kind of Fortran resources do you use?